# How to customize this theme?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, child-theme, theme-customizer, theme-options

I am working on the following theme. 
https://wordpress.org/themes/ultra/

Does anybody know how can I remove the margin between widgets in this theme?
How can I move the menu bar to a new line?

Comment: Which theme fo you mean? Url?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/themes/ultra/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the Navigation to a new Line:
Add `clear:left;` to the `.main-navigation` class in your styles.css

With Widgets I assume you mean the 3 sections with the blue graphic.. those have a horizontal padding of 25px and are evenly distributed by their width of 33.33333% -> look at the class `.sow-features-list .sow-features-feature`

Line 21 of your styles.css

```
.sow-features-list .sow-features-feature {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 25px; //change this line
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The first works fine. But I cannot find the padding in .sow-features-list .sow-features-feature. Should I look into the style.css or somewhere else?

Comment: edited my answer above

Comment: I am using the main style file, not the one inside the demo folder. In that case how can I change this padding?

Comment: I manually added widgets by myself. I need to remove the horizontal margin between them.

Comment: please create a new question and put your url to your site there so we can check your code / style.